Disease diagnosis of vegetarians
A 60 year old hindu widow came to an OPD with complains of lemon yellow color skin, red sore tongue, weakness, numbness. She was a vegetarian for 25-30 years. Her hemoglobin was 8 gm/dl.
She might be suffering from iron deficiency anemia because iron suppliment is very less in plant source.
Then again, she might be suffering from megaloblastic anemia because megaloblastic anemia is caused by vit-B12 deficiency and vit-B12 can only be taken from animal source, vit-B12 can not be taken from plant source.
So, my question is,
She is suffering from which disease? Give reasons for this?

Please show us your prior research when posting - at present it looks like you're wanting to use the site for completing your homework without you putting any effort in. We don't do that. Please also note, one diagnosis doesn't preclude the other. ("A patient can have as many damn diseases as they please",  often attributed to Dr. Theodore E. Woodward)
